# Logstash to SQL Server connection fail

Tags: sql-server, elk

I have got below error when I am trying to connect with SQL Server

> `error_message=>"Java::JavaLang::NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter"}
>   logstash_1       | [2019-12-05T07:52:10,649][ERROR][logstash.javapipeline    ] A plugin had an unrecoverable error. Will restart this plugin`

My ELK version is 7.4

Answer (score 0):

I just built-up the connection. It's an issue caused by latest version of ELK. (7.5.0) Here's work around in my article. The point is to copy the JDBC driver .jar to the logstash-core\lib.

Check here:

[My blog of workaround solution before Elastic stack solved their issue](https://datamansamxiao.wordpress.com/2019/12/06/using-elastic-search-connect-to-sql-database-and-text-querying-by-kibana/)

--
MUST remain:

> jdbc_driver_library => “"

Logstash config:

```
    input {
jdbc {
jdbc_connection_string => “jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=SAMXIAODEMO;integratedSecurity=false;"
jdbc_driver_library => “"
jdbc_driver_class => “com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
jdbc_user => “SQL DB account"
jdbc_password => “SQL DB password"
statement => “SELECT * FROM DB.SCHEMA.TABLE"
}
}
output {
elasticsearch {
hosts => [“localhost:9200″]
index => “your index name"
}
}
```

Comment: I'll soon come out an English version for this :P

Comment: its a mixed versison btw thanks for your answer but sorry to say i have used same logtash confiz then i got the error thoug i am able to connect in my sql

Comment: Have you checked the JRE setting? And there's also an issue if you did wrong query in `statement => " select ...."`

Comment: there is no chance of query wrong 100% sure about that :)  but as i have used docker so i placed jar file sqljdbc42.jar inside logstash

Comment: So did it work? I'm curious about it. Maybe it help the other docker users :). Thank you.

Comment: This didn't work for me. I am not using docker. Just a plain logstash conf file. Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68409727/logstash-error-javajavalangnoclassdeffounderror-unable-to-resolve